# ¿Cómo cerrar sesión con JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter-3

Chicos estoy atorado en este tema, y si si he revisado las demás preguntas pero ninguna es lo que busco.
Como cerrar la sesión de un usuario pasando N minutos mostrando una alerta antes.

tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero obviamente solo lo hace cuando carga la pagina, necesito cerrar la sesión pasados N minutos.
Gracias.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.confirm({
    title: '¡Alerta!',
    content: 'Ha sobrepasado el tiempo permitido',
    autoClose: 'logoutUser',
    buttons: {
      logoutUser: {
        text: 'Iniciar sesion',
        action: function () {
          $.alert('La sesión ha expirado');
          window.location.replace('../../index.php')
        }
      },
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Primero hay que ver como estás creando la sesión inicialmente para saber cómo destruirla, el proceso de redirección sería sencillo simplemente con un setTimeout()

Comment: Hola Jonathan las sesiones las creo con la libreria de CodeIgniter, sin mas.

Answer (score 1):

El tiempo de vida de la sesión es algo que dependerá de como configures el php y/o  el codelgniter, para que se entere el frontend de que es lo que está pasando con la sesión, se suele hacer algo llamado **heartbeat** (latido de corazón), que sería así:

1. En el servidor haces un servicio que diga únicamente si la sesion aún es válida o no, por ejemplo *sesion_valida.php* en donde seguramente verificarás algo como `if($this->session->userdata('nombre_de_sesion'))`.
2. En javaScript haces un ajax a *sesion_valida.php* cada cierto tiempo. Supongamos cada 2 segundos.
3. Si aún hay sesión válida no haces nada, si la sesión expiró lanzas el alert o lo que quieras.

Para hacer esto puedes usar `setInterval` o `setTimeout`, este sería un ejemplo usando `setInterval`:

```
function comprobamosSesion() {
  //Solo un ejémplo de un ajax
  fetch('http://mipagina.com/sesion_valida.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(mirespuesta) {
      if (!mirespuesta.sessionValida) {
        alert("la sesion no es valda!");// <-- Aquí sabemos que no es válida
        clearInterval(heartbeat);
      }
    });

}


const heartbeat = setInterval(() => {
  comprobamosSesion();
}, 2000);// <-- Cada 2 segundos verifica si aun hay sesión
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! lo resolví con un setTimeout()